# Make ng-repeat call a function again on model change

Tags: angularjs

I have a table with an ng-repeat over a function that I want to be rerendered after a user logs in. How do I make a view load the ng-repeat and again to triger the function. Is there a way to make an ng-repeat rerender on a change in the model?

Here is the view, to give an idea why a function is used instead of just looping over a model. The repeat in question is `ng-repeat="(index, event) in vm.getEvents(dayObject) track by $index"` :

```
<!-- CALENDAR NAV -->
<div class="calendar-nav">
    <div class="prev">
        <button class="btn btn-default pull-right" ng-click="vm.goToPrevWeek()" ng-disabled="vm.isCurrentWeek"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div class="date">
        <p class="text-primary text-center">{{vm.weekViewString}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="next">
        <button class="btn btn-default pull-left" ng-click="vm.goToNextWeek()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END CALENDAR NAV -->
<!-- CALENDAR HEADER -->
<div class="calendar-header">
    <div class="weekdate-header date-header day-1 split-{{vm.weekSplit}}" ng-class="{'today': dayObject.isToday}" ng-repeat="(index, dayObject) in vm.calendarDays track by $index">
        <div class="date-container"><span class="date">{{dayObject.day}}</span><span class="week-day"> {{dayObject.weekDay}}</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END CALENDAR HEADER -->
<!-- CALENDAR CONTENT -->
<div class="calendar-content">
    <div class="calendar-aside">
        <div class="day-hour" ng-repeat="(index, hourObject) in vm.calendarHours track by $index">
            <span class="hour">{{hourObject.hour}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="calendar-days">
        <div class="calendar-day day-col day-1 split-{{vm.weekSplit}}" ng-class="{'today': dayObject.isToday}" ng-repeat="(index, dayObject) in vm.calendarDays track by $index">
            <div class="mobile-day hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm">
                <div class="date-container"><span class="date">{{dayObject.day}}</span><span class="week-day"> {{dayObject.weekDay}}</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="day-hour hour-{{hourObject.number}}" ng-repeat="(index, hourObject) in vm.calendarHours track by $index">
                <div class="hour">
                    <div class="half-hour"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- CALENDAR EVENTS -->
            <div id="{{event.idName}}" class="event-container {{event.type}}" style="top: {{event.top}}px; left: {{event.left}}%; width: {{event.width}}%; height: {{event.height}}px;"
                 ng-repeat="(index, event) in vm.getEvents(dayObject) track by $index" ng-switch="event.type">
                <div class="buttons" ng-switch-when="">
                    <div class="amount">{{event.spotsAvailable}}</div>
                </div>
                <div class="buttons" ng-switch-when="success">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="buttons" ng-switch-when="full">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="text">
                    <span class="title">{{event.name}}</span>
                    <p class="locatie-time hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm"> <span>{{event.startsAt | date:'HH:mm' }}</span>&nbsp;-&nbsp;<span>{{event.endsAt | date:'HH:mm' }}</span> </p>
                    <span class="locatie-info">{{event.formattedAddress}}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- END CALENDAR EVENTS -->
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<!-- END CALENDAR CONTENT -->
```

Comment: It will rerender if the list that is being repeated over changes.

Comment: Since it is a function, you only know if it has changed by running it again. Would it work to pass a variable in the function if that variable changes, would that cause the function to be evaluated again?

Comment: I guess the only way is to loop over a list and have that list populated by the function I'm no looping over.

Comment: Is there a way to make a view to render again?

Comment: I get that it isn't a good idea to use a function, as **Pitfall #1: Scope digester and expressions** in http://thenittygritty.co/angularjs-pitfalls-using-scopes says _DO NOT use functions in expressions_, but it is dificult to get it out of my code. I tried half a day to replace the function but I didn't manage to get it working properly. Any pointers on what could be a way out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up replacing the function in the ng-repeat with a direct link to the data the function was returning and now the view is updating.